# How to use grep to extract file names at end of lines?

Tags: shell, grep

I have a log file which contains information such as output using
`ls *.CCD` from directory `/var/tmp/Person`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 bv90       dkas     153698  Nov 18 13:08 WE994002.CCD
```

I have many such lines.

If I do `grep .CCD /var/tmp/k.log | grep bv90 | grep "Nov 18"`, I am
getting the whole line back, but I only need `WE994002.CCD`. How can I
alter my command to print just the file name?

Answer (score 1):

Add an awk statement to parse the list, like so:

```
grep .CCD /var/tmp/k.log | grep bv90 | grep "Nov 18"| awk '{print $9}'
```

This awk statement space delimits the output and prints the ninth field.

in which case you can skip grep altogether, and it can be shortened to

```
awk '/.CCD$/ && /bv90/ && /Nov 18/ {print $9}' /var/tmp/k.log
```

Comment: If the file contains spaces and tab . in that case how to use it @Andrew

Comment: Awk considers 'white space' to be from any number (i.e. one or more) of 'spaces' or a 'tabs' next to each other. So, if the file contains spaces or tabs, or both, and even if there is more than one next to each other (e.g. 3 tabs and a space), awk considers it a single 'white space'.  No special treatment needed!  If your delimiter is NOT white space, then you must tell awk with -F option, and follow the -F option with the delimiter of your choice.  For example, if the example above used a colon delimited field instead of white space, pipe the output to awk like so: awk -F: '{print $9}'

Answer (score 1):

Print last column:

```
awk '{print $NF}' /var/tmp/k.log
```

or

```
grep .CCD /var/tmp/k.log | grep bv90 | grep "Nov 18" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: Note that `$NF` will give you the target of the symlink instead of the file name for files of type symlink. Anyway, we also have to assume that file names don't contain blanks or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

If using GNU grep, then the `-o` option may be relevant:

```
$ echo '-rwxr-xr-x 1 bv90 dkas 153698 Nov 18 13:08 WE994002.CCD' | grep -o '[^ ]*\.CCD$'
WE994002.CCD
```

This assumes that the file name you want to filter on contains no
space; the call to `grep -o` asks to print only the part of the line
that matches a sequence of non-space characters ending in `.CCD` at
the end of the line. The whole command would become:

```
</var/tmp/k.log grep bv90 | grep "Nov 18" | grep -o '[^ ]*\.CCD$'
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -n '/bv90.*Nov 18.*\.CCD$/ s/^.*Nov 18 ..:.. //p' logfile
```

Instead of extracting a specific field, this sed script deletes everything on the matching line up to and including the date and time string (and the space character immediately after).  This will leave only the filename, assuming there aren't any symlinks in the output listing....if there are any symlinks, they can be removed with:

```
sed -n '/bv90.*Nov 18.*\.CCD$/ { s/^.*Nov 18 ..:.. // ; s/ ->.*//; p}' logfile
```

Comment: If I do

Date=select to_char(sysdate-1,  'Mon. DD') from dual
sed -n '/bv90.*$DATE.*\.CCD$/ s/^.*$DATE..:.. //p' log file  > u.txt then its giving result as 01d25c                                                                                         >WE9944002.CCD @cas

Comment: you need to use double-quotes rather than single-quotes if you want to embed a variable into something like a sed script.  Try `sed -n "/bv90.*$DATE.*\.CCD$/ s/^.*$DATE ..:.. //p" log file > u.txt`.  btw, the `..:..` matches the HH:MM, and a space is needed between that and the `Mon DD`

Answer (score 0):

If there are no spaces in the filename, and no soft links, I would use AWK, as Cyrus described.

If there might be spaces in the filename, we can use spaces to describe all preceding fields, capture all the tokens that follow:

```
sed 's/\(\S\+\s\+\)\{8\}\(.*\)/\2/' logfile
```

The first set of parentheses describes a column, followed by whitespace.  This is repeated 8 times.  The 2nd set of parentheses captures the rest of the line, which the back reference \2 captures.

If you need to strip off soft links, I'm pretty sure we'll need another sed command, as cas described:

```
sed 's/\(\S\+\s\+\)\{8\}\(.*\)/\2/ ; s/ -> .*//'
```